# How do I insert a linebreak where the cursor is without entering into insert mode in Vim?

Tags: vim, performance, text-editor

Is possible to insert a line break where the cursor is in Vim without entering into insert mode? Here's an example (`[x]` means cursor is on `x`):

```
if (some_condition) {[ ]return; }
```

Occasionally, I might want to enter some more code. So I'd press <kbd>i</kbd> to get into insert mode, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the line break and then delete the extra space. Next, I'd enter normal mode and position the cursor before the closing brace and then do the same thing to get it on its own line.

I've been doing this a while, but there's surely a better way to do it?

Comment: You want to insert something without going into INSERT mode?

Comment: @jeremy-cantrell Yeah, just like "J" joins the next line and inserts a whitespace without going into INSERT mode!

Answer (score 124, accepted):

For the example you've given, you could use <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to replace a single character (the space) with Enter. Then, <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to move forward to the next space and repeat the last command.

Depending on your autoindent settings, the above may or may not indent the return statement properly. If not, then use <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> instead to replace the space with a newline, indent the line, and exit insert mode. You would have to replace the second space with a different command so you couldn't use '.' in this case.

Comment: 'f[space]' should be equivalent to 'W' (i.e. move to the next whitepsace)

Comment: 'W' moves one character too far, it moves to the next character *after* the next whitespace.

Comment: You could also use `>>` and `<<` to help indenting if you didn't want to go into insert mode with `s`.

Answer (score 14):

A simple mapping to break the line at the cursor by pressing Ctrl+Enter:

> `:nmap <c-cr> i<cr><Esc>`

essentially enters 'insert' mode, inserts a line break and goes back to normal mode.

put it in your .vimrc file for future use.

Answer (score 12):

Here's how to create a macro that inserts a newline at the cursor whenever you press 'g' while *not* in insert mode:

From within vim, type:

```
:map g i[Ctrl+V][Enter][Ctrl+V][Esc][Enter]
```

Where:

- [Ctrl+V] means *hold the Ctrl key and press 'v'*
- [Enter] means *press the Enter key*
- [Esc] means *press the Esc key*

You'll see the following at the bottom of your vim window until you press the final Enter:

```
:map g i^M^[
```

**Explanation:**

[Ctrl+V] means "quote the following character" -- it allows you to embed the newline and escape characters in the command.

So you're mapping the 'g' key to the sequence:

```
i [Enter] [Escape]
```

This is vim for *insert a newline before the cursor, then exit insert mode*.

**Tweaks:**

- You can replace the 'g' with any character that's not already linked to a command you use.
- Add more to the command, *e.g.* `f}i^M^[O`  -- This will **f**ind the **}** and **i**nsert another newline, then escape from insert mode and **O**pen an empty line for you to enter more code.
- You can add the command to your .vimrc or .exrc file to make it permanent.  Just omit the colon from the beginning, so the command starts with "map"

Enjoy!

Comment: You answered the badly phrased question in the subject, instead of the one in the posting. What he wants to know is how to easily get rid of the whitespace that was at the point where the line was broken but no longer serves a purpose.

Comment: Thanks.  Updated the "Tweaks" section to accomplish what (I think) the author requested.  When I tested it, vi automatically removed the extra spaces for me; use 'x' to delete them if yours doesn't.  And why do vi commands look like modem line noise?  :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you're usually expanding a one line block to three lines, try substitution.  Change the opening bracket into bracket/return, and the closing bracket into return/bracket.

The command for substituting bracket/return for bracket looks like this:

```
:s/{/{\r/
```

Since you want to use this often, you could map the full sequence to an unused keystroke like this:

```
:map <F7> :s/{/{\r/ ^M :s/}/\r}/ ^M
```

Where you see **^M** in the sequence, type **[Ctrl-V]**, then press **enter**.

Now with your cursor anywhere on your sample line, press the mapped key, and the carriage returns are added.

Check `:help map-which-keys` for advice on selecting unused keystrokes to map.

Comment: BTW: `g` is not mapped because it is used as 'namespace' key for many vim mappings consisting of two keystrokes (see `:h g`). So this mapping is actually a no-go.

Comment: Is there a good command that reports that `g` is already in use as a 'namespace' key?

Comment: Not in particular. As I said `:help g` is one way to see a list of default `g`+ something mappings. `z`, `[` `]` are further 'namespace' keys, see e.g. `:help index`. You can invoke `:verbose map g` to see all current defined mappings starting with g. Helpful webresources are http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif, http://vimcasts.org/blog/2014/02/follow-my-leader/, https://vimeo.com/85343734 (slides: https://speakerdeck.com/nelstrom/follow-my-leader)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're okay with mapping `K` to something else (choose a different key of your liking), and using marker `'` as a temporary marker is okay why not do this?

```
:nmap K m'a<CR><Esc>`'
```

now pressing K in normal mode over the character after which you want the line break to occur will split the line and leave the cursor where it was.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, when you split a line you either want to just insert a carriage return, or in the case that you're on a space, replace that with a carriage return. Well, why settle for one or the other? Here's my mapping for K:

```
"Have K split lines the way J joins lines
nnoremap <expr>K getline('.')[col('.')-1]==' ' ? "r<CR>" : "i<CR><Esc>"
```

I use the ternary operator to condense the two actions into one key map. Breaking it down, `<expr>` means the key map's output can dynamic and in this case hinges on the condition `getline('.')[col('.')-1]==' '` which is the long winded way to ask vim if the character under the cursor is a space. Finally, the familiar ternary operator `? :` either replaces the space with linebreak (`r<CR>`) or inserts a new one (`i<CR><Esc>`)

Now you have a lovely sister key map to the `J` command.

Comment: This is pretty slick. I'm not sure if I've ever intentionally used K, but this might make it worth getting rid of or remapping elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Vim will automatically kill any whitespace to the right of the cursor if you break a line in two while `autoindent` (or any other indentation aid) is enabled.

If you do not want to use any of those settings, use `s` instead of `i` in order to **s**ubstitute your new text for the blank rather than just inserting. (If there are multiple blanks, put the cursor on the leftmost and use `cw` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

In fact you need the following combined operations:

1. Press <kbd>v</kbd> to enter Visual Mode
2. Select the line you want to split
3. Press `:` to enter in Command Mode
4. `s/\s/\r/g`
5. Done

Answer (score 1):

If you have the input:

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd
```

and want to output

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

You can use the command

```
f r<ENTER>;.;.
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this key mapping in your vimrc

```
:map <C-m> i<CR><Esc>h
```

Then press Ctrl+m if you want to use it in your vim.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the built-in mapping `gs` is not a useful mapping (put vim to sleep), one could use this for splitting:

```
nmap gs i<CR><ESC>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) you can use gql which will split a line without entering insert mode, but may not always maintain indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the most faithful implementation of what I'd expect the opposite behaviour to `J`

```
nnoremap S i<cr><esc>^mwgk:silent! s/\v +$//<cr>:noh<cr>`w
```

It does the simplistic new line at cursor, takes care of any trailing whitespace on the previous line if there are any present and then returns the cursor to the correct position.

<kbd>i</kbd> <kbd><cr></kbd> <kbd><esc></kbd> - this is one of the most common solutions suggested, it doesn't delete non-whitespace characters under your cursor but it also leaves you with trailing whitespace

<kbd>^mw</kbd> - goto start of new line and create a mark under `w`

<kbd>gk</kbd> - go up one line

<kbd>:silent! s/\v +$//</kbd><kbd><cr></kbd> - regex replace any whitespace at the end of the line

<kbd>:noh</kbd><kbd><cr></kbd> - Clear any search highlighting that the regex might have turned on

<kbd>`w</kbd> - return the the mark under `w`

Essentially combines the best of both <kbd>r</kbd><kbd><esc></kbd><kbd><cr></kbd> and <kbd>i</kbd><kbd><cr></kbd><kbd><esc></kbd>

Note: I have this bound to <kbd>S</kbd> which potentially overwrites a useful key but it is a synonym for <kbd>cc</kbd> and since I don't use it as often as I do splits I am okay with overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

`o` `ESC` command will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a keymapping for neovim

```
keymap.set("n", "<leader>nl", "i<CR><Esc>", {noremap = true})
```

Answer (score -1):

This mapping will break up any one-line function you have. Simply put your cursor on the line and hit 'g' in normal mode:

```
:map g ^f{malr<CR>`a%hr<CR>`a
```

This assumes that you have a space after the opening brace and a space before the closing brace. See if that works for you.