# Vim split line command

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I insert a linebreak where the cursor is without entering into insert mode in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237383/how-do-i-insert-a-linebreak-where-the-cursor-is-without-entering-into-insert-mod)

In vim, <kbd>J</kbd> joins the next line to the current line.  Is there a similar one-key (or relatively short) command to split a line at a given cursor position?  I know it be done with a simple macro, but it seems like if the <kbd>J</kbd>-command exists there should be a similar function.  I've tried searching for it, but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Does this help? [How do I insert a linebreak where the cursor is without entering into insert mode in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237383/how-do-i-insert-a-linebreak-where-the-cursor-is-without-entering-into-insert-mode)

Comment: No, I as really looking to see if maybe there was some base command I had overlooked or been unable to find that someone else here might know.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't think that there is a single key command for this. The best you can do with stock vim is probably <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: "<Esc>i<Enter><Esc>" Would probably be better

Comment: Better: `r<Enter>`.

Comment: r<enter> loses a char, but good if it's a space.

Comment: @AndyStewart `r<cr>` is bad as it can lose a character. I don't know why that answer has 50+ votes. The accepted answer is the only correct answer. You can also do `a<cr><esc>` depending on if you want to break after or before something.

Comment: `r<cr>` is good as it does the opposite of `J`, which adds a space.

Answer (score 190):

<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> while on whitespace will do it. That's two keystrokes.

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  I'm often wanting to split between two adjacent html tags with no space between.

Comment: @dburke In that case, put the `s` mapping here (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_a_single_character) in your `.vimrc` and use `<s><Enter>`.

Comment: `i` `Enter` will split the line between two adjacent html tags with no space between. @dburke

Answer (score 36):

My solution was to remap the K key since I never use the default action (look up the word under cursor with "man"), and my previous editor used Alt+j and Alt+k to join and split lines, respectively.

```
:nnoremap K i<CR><Esc>
```

This rolls those three annoying keystrokes into one.

There's probably a more sophisticated way to also eliminate any trailing whitespace, but I prefer to strip all trailing whitespace on write.

Comment: This is great!  Usually accidentally pressing `K` is disastrous for me because of the stupid `man` page functionality, but now I get to replace that with something that's actually useful.

Comment: This is a good redefine, but the default behavior of `K` shouldn't be thought as strictly `man` only. Many plugins redefine `K` as to lookup the docs in the context language. In PHP, for instance, `K` would take me to php.net documentations...

Answer (score 23):

No.  I've now read enough answers to conclude that there is no such command.

Easy answer:
Pressing 'Enter' while in insert will do it; but you're right, there oughtta be a key for it in command mode.  I've wondered, too.

Since everyone has a favorite workaround, I will share mine. The assumption is that I will do *anything* to avoid having to reach for the Esc key.

**ylprX** ... where 'X' is the inserted character, which can even be a *newline*.

So, 'yl' is yank on char to the right, 'p' = paste the char, 'r' is replace that char; then you just type the new char.  *That's* how much I hate using Escape.

(That was 'l', as in "move right", BTW)

Comment: I'm gonna go file a feature request.  Who's with me?!

Comment: To "improve" vi again? (Big grin). My guess is if everyone wants it and it doesn't exist, there must be a reason.  What I *really* want is an "insert n characters" cmd that stays out of "insert mode".

Comment: Recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397229/reaching-up-to-hit-the-escape-key

Comment: @gbarry Wow - have you considered remapping CapsLock to do the Esc function?

Comment: @willoller that was my immediate though too.

Comment: Saw this and thought of this thread: http://blog.makezine.com/2012/06/25/vim-clutch/

Comment: @gbarry http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/#controlescape

Answer (score 12):

Old thread, but I dont use "K" for the man page lookup or whatever magic it does. So I have this mapping in my .vimrc:

```
map K i<Enter><Esc>
```

I figured since "J" is join, "K" can be krack or something. :)

Comment: I remapped <CR> as <Esc> so for me this is the best answer :)

Comment: or just: kut (as cut) ^_^

Answer (score 10):

You can split lines if you can create a regular expression for the location to add the split.  For example if you want to split the lines at each semicolon, you can use the following substitution:

%s/;/^v^m/g

to great effect

Answer (score 0):

Jed's answer is most useful. I would like to add that I needed the "control-V-alternative", i.e. control-Q:
%s/;/^q^m/g