# How to break a line in vim in normal mode?

Tags: vim, macvim

I would like to break a line (at the location of the cursor) in to two lines without leaving normal mode (entering insert or command-line mode). Is this possible?

I currently get to the location I want and hit 'i' to enter insert mode, 'enter' to break the line in two, then 'esc' to return to normal mode.

I am not trying to set a maximum line length or do any syntax or anything like that. I just want to break one line into two lines without leaving normal mode. 'J' joins the line the cursor is on to the line below it, which is handy. I want the opposite -- to break one line into two with a single command.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
:nnoremap <NL> i<CR><ESC>
```

then just press Ctrl-J whenever you want to split a line.

Comment: That is exactly what I was hoping for. I find it odd that this isn't a built in command in vim, but I added the line to my .vimrc file and am happily chugging along.

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate discovering a feature I never knew I needed until now... ;-)

Comment: I think it is better to use `:noremap` rather than `:map`, and that it is even better to use `:nnoremap` in this case as the question states *normal mode*.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. When hitting 'i' to enter insert mode, 'enter' to break the line in two, then 'esc' to return to normal mode, the new line is at the same indent as the previous one, and using this trick there's always an extra character. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS: There does seem to be some kind of formatting action that takes place after the line split.  That doesn't happen when you enter the commands manually.  I'm not sure what the origin of that is.  I'll post the result if I figure it out.

Comment: I think I figured it out: remove the blank space between "<CR> <ESC>". The command should be: ":nnoremap <NL> i <CR><ESC>". It's working in my vim.

Comment: Great!  
Because <NL>, the press of [Ctrl]+[Enter] works too.  
(But watch out the "vim-LaTeX-suite": it is re-map the <NL>!)

Answer (score 53):

I don't know of a single key command, but a lot of times I do "r" then "Enter" to break a line.

"r" replaces the current character under the cursor without going into insert mode.  This may not be what you want if you don't want to replace a character...

Comment: Does not work for me… it inserts `^M` character. Probably it depends on `&fileformat`.

Comment: @Benoit, 'fileformat' makes no difference while editing; it's only used for read and write.

Answer (score 34):

Similar to other answers but doesn't replace the current character.

`R<enter>`

No remaps required.

Comment: Close, but leaves the user in Insert mode, he wants to end up in Normal mode.

Answer (score 31):

put cursor in position and...

```
  r<Enter>
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the top answer since it requires no additional mappings.

Comment: Because it replaces character in the current position with a \n

Comment: also because you might want to break the line on a non white space character, for example at `(|(arg)` which means `arg)` will go on the next line but you lose one of the parens

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this isn't possible without entering insert mode.  You can however macro it with something like (replace Z with whatever key you want to use)

```
nmap Z i<cr><esc>k$
```

basically this maps the key 'Z' to enter insert mode 'i', insert a carriage return '`<cr>`', leave insert mode '`<esc>`', go up a line 'k' and finally go to the end of the line '$'

Answer (score 3):

You can use recording.

1. Place your cursor where you would like to insert a line break.
2. Type `qa` to start recording into register `a` (you can use another register other than `a` if you want.)
3. Then type `i` (switch to insert mode), <kbd>Return</kbd> (insert newline), <kbd>escape</kbd> (exit insert mode), `q` (ends recording.)

Now you can invoke this sequence of keys by typing `@a` (where `a` is the register number you used when you started the recording), just keep moving the cursor where you want to insert a newline and type `@a`.

Answer (score 2):

Per this duplicate question: [How do I insert a linebreak where the cursor is without entering into insert mode in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237383/how-do-i-insert-a-linebreak-where-the-cursor-is-without-entering-into-insert-mode)

From within vim, type:

```
:map g i[Ctrl+V][Enter][Ctrl+V][Esc][Enter]
```

This maps the G key to macro I [Enter] [Escape]

Comment: Thanks. I did some searching before posting but I guess I didn't use the right terms. That was a good discussion you  linked to, and I feel bad that I posted a duplicate, but I think I got a slightly more elegant answer from Amardeep.

Comment: I find it's better to use Vim's key notation (e.g. <CR> and <Esc>) for maps.  Also, be more specific regarding map modes.

Answer (score -1):

In normal mode, Press the character 'O' then 'Esc'. No mapping needed.

Comment: This is just wrong. I doesn't split, it adds an empty line.