# How does vim break 1 line into 2 lines under normal mode, by 1 type?

Tags: vim, line, break, mode

Under normal mode, to merge 2 lines, we can press `J`. But how to break one line (somewhere in the middle) into 2 lines? Now I can only press `i` to enter insert mode and press `<CR>`.

Is there a command under normal mode, one type to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. However you can map it like `nnoremap K i<CR><esc>`

Comment: `K` is so useful in normal mode, I won't suggest this mapping ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As per [How to break a line in vim in normal mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961730/how-to-break-a-line-in-vim-in-normal-mode)

`r<Enter>` comes closest to what you are trying to do, although `<CR>` will replace the character under the cursor. It works for me because I usually break a line on a white space.